# Is $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathcal O_K)$ dense in $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, number-theory, real-numbers

Let $K$ be a real quadratic number field of discriminant $D>0$ with $\mathcal O_K$ being its ring of integers.

There are two embeddings $K \hookrightarrow \mathbb R$ and using them $\mathcal O_K \hookrightarrow \mathbb R^2$ can be reagarded as discrete subgroup of $\mathbb R^2$. But when you regard only one embedding $\mathcal O_K \hookrightarrow \mathbb R$ is a dense subgroup of $\mathbb R$.

Now let us consider $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathcal O_K)$. Embedded into $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb R)^2$ this is still discrete. But if you regard only one embedding $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathcal O_K) \hookrightarrow \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$ this is not discrete anymore. For example you have

$$\left\{\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & \lambda\\
0 & 1\\
\end{matrix}\right) \in \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathcal O_K) : \lambda \in \mathcal O_K\right\}
$$
whose closure is
$$\left\{\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & x\\
0 & 1\\
\end{matrix}\right) \in \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb R) : x \in \mathbb R\right\}.
$$
On the other hand I'm not sure if for all $x \in \mathbb R$ the matrix $\operatorname{diag}(x,x^{-1})$ is part of the closure of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathcal O_K)$.

**So my question is**: What is the closure of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathcal O_K)$ in $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$? Is $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathcal O_K)$ maybe dense in $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is dense because $\pmatrix{d&0\\0&d^{-1}}$ is in the closure : take $a,b\in O_K$ such that $a- d,b- d^{-1}$ are very small, $u\in (0,1)$ is the fundamental unit such that $O_K^\times=\pm u^\Bbb{Z}$,  $|ab-1|\in [u^{2n+2},u^{2n}]$,
then $$\pmatrix{a&(ab-1)u^{-n}\\ u^n &b}\in SL_2(O_K)$$

Next $\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0},\pmatrix{1&*\\0&1},\pmatrix{1&0\\*&1}$ are in the closure which must be $$SL_2(\Bbb{R})=\pmatrix{1&0\\*&1}\pmatrix{*&0\\0&*}\pmatrix{1&*\\0&1}\cup \pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}\pmatrix{*&0\\0&*}\pmatrix{1&*\\0&1}$$

Answer (score 1):

A Zariski-dense subgroup in $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{R})$ is either discrete or dense (indeed the Lie algebra of its closure is an ideal, hence 0 or everything)

Since your group contains $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ it is Zariski-dense. Since it contains unipotent matrices with coefficients in $O_K$, it is not discrete. Hence it's dense.